# Compile Windows DLL for WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, compilation, platform, visual-studio-2013

I've got the c# source for a DLL that works on windows 8... I would like to use it in a windows phone 8 application. Is there an easy way to change the target platform of the project to WP8 and then compile for that? I assume it will have to be compiled as a Windows Phone Class Library but that should be fine. I'm using VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the library. If it has any dependencies to the full .net framework, it will most likely not work. If its just a generic Library, you should be able to make a new Windows Phone Class Library Project and copy over the source.

I guess, you'd simply have to try that. Maybe you can bypass some of the dependencies and rewrite these sections with Windows Phone compatible code.